# How to stream captured video from a client to the server using DirectShow.Net

Tags: video-streaming, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

My idea is to have a service or app running on my home PC that will enable me to view my home, outside conditions, etc while I'm away. I'm using DirectShow.Net and am starting to understand the concept of the Filters, Graphs, and GMFBride. I've been able to get a preview to render, and I'm starting to wire up the streaming portion. But here is where my issues begin. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

What I was thinking was to be able to convert the captured video into some type of MemoryStream, cyclic data buffer, or something; and then read it from the server to show on a web page. So if you could help me the logic of how to do this conversion I would greatly appreciate it.

But I'm pretty new to this, so if what I'm thinking is wrong, then please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have such an application, and it works like this:

- it constructs DirectShow graph with capture device
- it adds sample grabber into it to fetch audio and video samples

then

- using `IWMWritter` interface (Windows Media) it compresses the raw data and creates a stream for either sending to the windows media server or for direct access from the outside.

BTW; it won't be easy - you have two technologies to learn: DirectSHOW.net and Windows Media Framework.

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/

NOTE: if by SERVICE you mean Windows Service, forget it.  You can't have service that accesses audio cards correctly on Windows.  Even if you don't use audio, it will behave in very erratic fashion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a start. And thanks for the warning on the Service, I guess I won't go down that road. What is the interface for the sample grabber?  I just looked over the Windows Media foundation, and one question about that is; does the hosting web server have to have the Windows Media Server for this to work? (That may be a stupid question.)

Comment: First - don't use Windows Media Foundation, use Windows Media Format SDK.  Sample grabber: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376984(v=vs.85).aspx?ppud=4